# Dynamic size Multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic

How can I create Dynamic size Multidimensional array in python?

Aim is to create a dynamic size arrays within arrays, e.g.:

```
ExampleArray{
   book1 : { key:val }
   book2 : { key:val }
}
```

This returns an error:

```
ExampleArray = {}
ExampleArray['book1']['key'] = 'val';
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

replace by

```
ExampleArray = {}
ExampleArray['book1'] = {}
ExampleArray['book1']['key'] = 'val'
```

when you do  `ExampleArray['book1']` you are trying to access it but no to affect it, therefore since the key does not exists it throws an exception

you have to affect a value to `ExampleArray['book1']` (in this case `dict()`)

PS. loose the ; at the end of the lines. you are not doing C or C++

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

ExampleArray = defaultdict(dict)

ExampleArray['book1']['key'] = 'val'

print(ExampleArray) # defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'book1': {'key': 'val'}})
```